# Hibernate / JPA: How to map two @Immutable entities (views of same table) with another entity by same parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

There is a table ORDERS from which were created views ORDER_VIEW_A and ORDER_VIEW_B.

I have created entity classes OrderViewA and OrderViewB where in each of them is mapping on entity named 'TransactionRecord'.

It is @OneToOne relationship.
There is column ORDER_ID in TRANSACTION_RECORD table and field orderId in TransactionRecord entity.

Field orderId is same for OrderViewA.id and for OrderViewB.id, cause views are selected from the same table.

My question is, how to map in Hibernate two views in OneToOne relationship with another entity by same field.

My code looks like this and it doesn't work in any way, Hibernate always end up with:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced property not a
>   (One|Many)ToOne: com.example.app.model.TransactionRecord.orderId in
>   mappedBy of com.example.app.model.views.OrderViewA.orderViewA

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "ORDER_VIEW_A")
public class OrderViewA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orderId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private IntegrationRecord orderARecord;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "ORDER_VIEW_B")
public class OrderViewB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "orderId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private IntegrationRecord orderBRecord;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION_RECORD")
public class TransactionRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Long orderId;

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private OrderViewA orderViewA;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private OrderViewB orderViewB;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Which `@Immutable` is this?

Comment: org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable

Comment: Probably a long-shot, but try changing the `@OneToOne(mappedBy` in both views to the `orderViewA` and `orderViewB`, rather than orderId, and have `referencedColumnName = "order_id"` . I'm not even sure you can have multiple joins on the same column in Hibernate.